# Jackson deserialization of list, skip elements without specific field

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I would like to deserialize a JSON with Jackson to a `List<User>` like

```
class Users {
    private List<User> users;
}

class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

I would like:

- `id` to be a mandatory field, so if a user element does not contain an id, it should be skipped
- `name` fied to be optional, so if a user element does not contain a name it should be included to the list with `null` name (or even with a Java 8 Optional value if possible)

So for example in the following JSON

```
{
    "users" : [{
            "id" : 123,
            "name" : "Andrew"
        }, {
            "name" : "Bob"
        }, {
            "id" : 789
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

the second user should be skipped during deserialization, the third one should be included in the list with empty name.
Is it possible using Jackson?

Comment: check this https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations. Please show the code for the deserializer you have written

Comment: did you try @JsonProperty(required=true) for id property?

Comment: @DhruvPal I use a Feign client which uses a `ObjectMapper`
@Jayz I tried it, but this way items without `id` will be included with null id value.

Comment: You can create a custom deserializer for this task

Comment: @SachinGupta could you please show me an example?

Answer (score 2):

I think a custom deserializer can do the task as shown below.

```
    public class UserListDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<User>> {

    @Override
    public List<User> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = p.readValueAsTree();
        Iterator<JsonNode> it = node.elements();
        List<User> userList=new ArrayList<>();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode user = it.next();
            if (user.get("id") != null) {
                User userObj = new User();
                userObj.setId(user.get("id").intValue());
                userObj.setName(user.get("name")!=null?user.get("name").textValue():null);
                userList.add(userObj);
            }

        }
        return userList;
    }
}
```

and annotate your Users class as shown below.

```
public class Users {
    @JsonDeserialize(using=UserListDeserializer.class)
    private List<User> users;
}
```

Comment: note that this solution does not skip the unwanted elements, i.e. at some point you have ALL the JsonNode objects in memory... i only presume that if this was okay with OP he would simply iterate the result after the whole thing is parsed, and throw away objects that he does not like

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation .

Somthing like this :) :

```
     public static void main(String[] args)  {
          String json = "{ \"users\" : [{\"id\" : 123, \"name\" : \"Andrew\"}, {\"name\" : \"Bob\"}, {\"id\" : 789}]}";
          try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Users users = mapper.readValue(json, Users.class);

       String jsonInString= mapper.writeValueAsString(selectUsers(users.getUsers()));
            System.out.println(jsonInString);

          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

  private static Collection<User> selectUsers(List<User> users) {
    return org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils.select(users, new org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate<User>() {

      @Override
      public boolean evaluate(User user) {
        return user.getId() != null;
      }

    });
  }

     public static class Users implements Serializable {



        private List<User> users;

        /**
         * @return the users
         */
        public List<User> getUsers() {
          return users;
        }

        /**
         * @param users the users to set
         */
        public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
          this.users = users;
        }

      }
      @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
      public static class User implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4223240034979295550L;

        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        public Integer id;

        @NotNull
        public String name;

        /**
         * @return the id
         */
        public Integer getId() {
          return id;
        }

        /**
         * @param id the id to set
         */
        public void setId(Integer id) {
          this.id = id;
        }

        /**
         * @return the name
         */
        public String getName() {
          return name;
        }

        /**
         * @param name the name to set
         */
        public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
        }
      }
```

Output :[{"id":123,"name":"Andrew"},{"id":789,"name":null}]

Answer (score -1):

You can filter the unwanted items in the setter:

```
public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users.stream().filter(u -> u != null && u.id != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here is my complete test class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String json = "{ \"users\" : [{\"id\" : 123, \"name\" : \"Andrew\"}, {\"name\" : \"Bob\"}, {\"id\" : 789}]}";
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Users users = mapper.readValue(json, Users.class);
        System.out.println(users.users);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static class Users
{
    private List<User> users;

    public void setUsers(List<User> users)
    {
        this.users = users.stream().filter(u -> u != null && u.id != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

public static class User
{
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return"{id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "}";
    }
}
```

output:

`[{id=123, name=Andrew}, {id=789, name=null}]`